# When should one say "El Maleh" if the yahrtzeit falls on a non-Torah-reading day?

Tags: tefilla, yahrtzeit

As far as I have seen, "El Maleh" for the departed is said only a day when the Torah is read, assuming that *Tachanun* is said that day (I'm not referring to its recital during *Yizkor* or Shabbat mincha.)

If a person's *yahrtzeit* falls on a non-Torah-reading day, when should the deceased's relative say *El Maleh* - before or after the *yahrtzeit* date? Does it not matter? Is there a different protocol for the first *Yahrtzeit*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[When to do "missing" Nissan "Kel Maleh"?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/56498/when-to-do-missing-nissan-kel-maleh)
According to the answer given here one should say the kel maleh on the shabbat preceding the yahrtzeit or the last shabbat before the yahrtzeit that one can say a kel maleh.

Comment: Hi Yosef - A belated welcome to Mi Yodeya. I have seen you post a few previous questions. I didn't realize that the 2nd answer, there, answers this question, as well.